# Laptop - touchpad not moving cursor - newbie

Tags: touchpad

So I have ultrabook - UMAX VisionBook 14Wa Pro - which is somekind lowend Apollo Lake laptop. /N3450/
I tried installing latest Ubuntu on it, and it works great. BUT. Touchpad doesnt register / move cursor. Weirdly, click sometimes / somehow working. I tried installik latest kernel for ubuntu via tutorials (now I have 5.1 generic) and it still not working. When I disable and enable touchpad via key several times it starts working without problem for few seconds and than again, just die...
Im really newbie, but also raging. Is there any way to make it work ?

/ also tried latest 19.04 release.. Still same problem.

```
michal@Michal-VisionBook:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS0001:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 PC Camera: PC Camera              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
michal@Michal-VisionBook:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to AK, this was easy to find: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400262, see if it helps you.

Comment: Sadly no, still same.(I offcourse edit commands to reflect my ALPS0001 device